# Reactjs react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Cannot realize how it works,
Have two routes, but in two cases opening only the one route with path '/'.

```
<HashRouter>
<Routes>
<Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
<Route path='/about' element={<AboutScreen />}></Route>
<Routes/>
<HashRouter/>
```

React router dom version 6.0.2

Comment: With BrowserRouter working fine, but HashRouter for some reason don't put hash sign automatically in address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have wrapped the routes, but routes has to be wrapped inside `<Routes></Routes>` if u are using `react-router-dom v6` otherwise you have to use a `<Switch></Switch>` if u are using <= `v5`. This helps in just picking up one of the routes while checking for route requested.

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='/about' element={<AboutScreen />}></Route>
   <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

**`Note`: Check them once and comment if any query. Since, I haven;t seen ur code, then, I can suspect this issue**

`Also check if order of route inclusion also effects the result`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route>
<Switch>
<SecureRoute exact path='/'>
     <HomeScreen />}
</SecureRoute>
<SecureRoute exact path='/about'>
      <AboutScreen />
</SecureRoute>
</Switch>
</Route>
```

**edited - how about writing them like this?

Comment: Tried like this, the error occurred - HomeScreen is not a Route component

Comment: @VadymFilatov how about this one? I've edited the code a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import HomeScreen from "Path of HomeScreen";
import AboutScreen from "Path of AboutScreen";

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={HomeScreen}></Route>
          <Route path='/about' component={AboutScreen}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Both Route inside Routes, and HashRouter. And I tried with 'exact' and without, same result

Comment: @VadymFilatov I have edited my answer please try like this.

Answer (score 0):

React routes work by priority from top to bottom; any rule that matches will be evaluated.. and the / matches both / and /about.

So to be able to solve your problem, you either have to put the / route at the end of all routes or you can add an exact keyword on the / route to tell the router that this has to match exactly for it to work..

```
<Route path='/' exact element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
<Route path='/about' element={<AboutScreen />}></Route>
```

or

```
<Route path='/about' element={<AboutScreen />}></Route>
<Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
```

I usually prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here for you minimal example of routing with `react-router` v6.

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


const Home = () => <div>Hello HomePage </div>;

const AboutPage = () => <div>Hello AboutPage </div>;

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Check out [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-goodall-kuhiu?file=/src/index.js:0-448)